# Replace Text With Spaces & Special Characters

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying make a bash script to enable auto-login in Debian. I need to replace this line:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty
```

with this one:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty tty1 --autologin $uName
```

I've tried this, but I receive errors because of the **: -- $** and the spaces

```
uName=Sean
Old="1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty"
New="1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty tty1 --autologin $uName"

cat /location/file.txt | sed s/$Old/$New/
```

I've tried replacing **38400 tty** to something else, but the file has multiple lines containing **38400 tty**. I also tried replacing the top line, but it needs to be further down in the config. I can't change it based on the line number since some configs may be on a diffrent number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use an alternate regex delimiter like `~` for `sed` since your sed has `/` in input string.
2. Avoid using `cat` and `sed`
3. Use double quote for variable expansion

Sed command:

```
sed "s~$Old~$New~" /location/file.txt
```